# Markov chains on a polyhedron

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, random-walks

A modification of a question from Gerard Letac (1976): A m-sided q-adjacent-faced polyhedron has one of its faces "up."  Each round, the polyhedron rolls so that any of the adjacent faces is now up.  For example, with a 6 sided dice (m = 6, q = 4), if 1 is up, the dice can roll so that 2, 3, 4, or 5 is up with equal probability (1/4).  It can only roll so that any of the adjacent faces is up.  It continues to roll randomly for n rounds.

Before you begin the rolling, I'm wondering what the probability distribution is for which face is up in the nth round.  Back to my example, if the polyhedron is a 6-sided dice and n = 2, we know that in the first round

Pr(face up = 2) = Pr(face up = 3) = Pr(face up = 4) = Pr(face up = 5) = (1/4)

and that in the second round

Pr(face up = 1) = Pr(face up = 6) = (1/4), and Pr(face up = 2) = Pr(face up = 3) = Pr(face up = 4) = Pr(face up = 5) = 1/8  .

But I have no idea how to find the general form solution given m, q, and n.

There are some papers that look at similar questions (Letac & Takacs, 1979, 1980; Sarkar, 2006) but nothing that addresses the total probability distribution.

Comment: Polygon, or polyhedron? Dice are not polygons.

Comment: Edited to reflect this mistake.

Comment: I don't know that I would expect there to be a nice closed-form expression.  Most questions like this look for asymptotics instead.

Comment: As it is a Markov chain, the probability distribution is given by the powers of the transition matrix, and the entries in the powers satisfy a linear, constant coefficient, homogeneous recurrence, so everything can be expressed explicitly in terms of the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the transition matrix. But I think you need more than $m$, $q$, and $n$. The polyhedron need not be fully symmetric.